# How to change form values on edit?

Tags: django

I'm beginner in Django.

I need to change form field value if other field is editing.

So, if I typed `val1` and `val2` in webform, `val3` is calculating automatically before press save button.

Like in MS Excel, if I have cell `C1` with function `=A1+B1`. When I change `A1` or `B1` values then `C1` value will automatically change.

```
class DealForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Deal
    fields = ['status', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3']
    widgets = {
        'status': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'val1': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'val2': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'val3': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }


class Deal(models.Model):
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True)   
val1 = models.FloatField(null = True, blank=True)    
val2 = models.FloatField(null = True, blank=True)    
val3 = models.FloatField(null = True, blank=True)


class DealCreate(View):
def get(self, request):
    form = DealForm()
    return render(request, 'portfolio/deal_create.html', context={'form':form})

def post(self, request):
    bound_form = DealForm(request.POST)

    if bound_form.is_valid():
        new_deal = bound_form.save()
        return redirect(new_deal)
    return render(request, 'portfolio/deal_create.html', context={'form':bound_form})






<script>
function calcCounterVol(){
var val1 = document.getElementsByName('val1').value
var val2 = document.getElementsByName('val2').value
document.getElementByName('val3').value = parseInt(val1)+parseInt(val2)}
</script>


 <form>
<div class="form-row mx-1">
<div class="form-group border col-md-6">
  <div class="form-row border mt-1">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label>Status</label>
      {{form.status}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label>Val1</label>
      {{form.val1}}
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label>Val2</label>
      {{form.val2}}
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label>Val3</label>
      {{form.val3}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: If your requirement is to add both the values as per the input value, why don't you do it in the backend itself, such computations are always good to be done in the backend rather than the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in javascript. you can see what are the names of element by inspecting the page and calculate like this:

```
<script>
    function calculateVal3(){
    var val1 = document.getElementsByName('val1').value
    var val2 = document.getElementsByName('val2').value
    document.getElementByName("val3").value = parseInt(val1)+parseInt(val2)    
}
</script>
```

Keep it in your template.

and you can pass on change event in attrs attribute  like this

```
class DealForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
    model = Deal
    fields = ['status', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3']
    widgets = {
        'status': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'val1': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'val2': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','onchange':'calculateVal3()'}),
        'val3': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

Comment: Great thanks for answer. But in my HTML it doesnt works:

Comment: I've added HTML to topic. Please, look at it.